# Will a long-integer work on a 32 bit system?

Tags: c#, long-integer

If I understand it right an int-variable is saving in 32 bit, restricting it to -2 billion to 2 billion something. However if I use a long-variable it will save in 64 bit allowing a lot more numbers to be stored. I'm sitting on a 64 bit system, but will my code run well on a 32 bit system if I store data in 64 bit?

Thank you!

Comment: it has nothing to do with a 32 or 64 bit system, it is just the length of the data. if you need a bigger range, use more bits

Comment: @Alexei Read the Q more closely. Asker knows that int is 32 bit and long is 64 bit.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't you worry about that. The `long` value will be stored in 2 memory addresses. `Int64`/`long` will always be 64bit, and `Int32`/`int` will always be 32bit.

There are a few implications (concerning memory space and performance), but the most noticeable may be that write/read operations won't be atomic on 32bit systems, but you shouldn't expect them to be atomic anyway, since the c# specification makes no such guarantee.

Either way, the point is: this is not something you should ever worry about - the CLR abstracts these things away. Use whichever type suits you best.

Comment: Lack of atomicity is not the only implication. There is a performance hit too. And a space hit.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Then I will proceed with my basic understanding of coding with a bit more confidence!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for pointing that out, I've rephrased that sentence.

Comment: This sentence also seems unrelated to the question asked: *The long value will be stored in 2 memory addresses. Int64/long will always be 64bit, and Int32/int will always be 32bit.* The asker already knows that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, I didn't want to assume that he did. The question was a bit broad ("but will my code run well on a 32 bit system if I store data in 64 bit?") and it implied a certain amount of uncertainty. So I thought mentioning that would do no harm, and it would strengthen the point that this is not something he should worry about, that it won't interfere with the correctness of the program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The asker is concerned that an int64 might not work on a 32 bit system.  That implies that they think all integers are stored in exactly one word.  The answer states that it will work correctly, and the reason it works correctly is that it stores the int across multiple words.  It's highly relevant.

Comment: @Servy I read the question completely differently. The first sentence seemed clear to me. And this answer seems to suggest that the asker should be content to use `long` instead of `int` without there being consequences. Sometimes there are consequences.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. but i have a question, In the c#9 we have nint type and i would ask you, should we use nint in new version in order to preventing dividing long into two parts on 32 bit systems? I mean, if we know our code might be executed on 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 10):

On a 32 bit system, operations on a 32 bit integer can be performed in a single machine register. But operations on a 64 bit integer require two machine registers, and are quite a bit less efficient than 32 bit operations. And of course, being twice the size, `long` uses more memory than `int`. If you have arrays of these types then you will consume your cache twice as fast if you use `long`. That can also have performance implications.

So, if you can use `int`, you should prefer it to `long`. However, if the 32 bits of range afforded by `int` are not sufficient for the correctness of your program, you would need to use `long`.

Of course, even though operations on 64 bit integers, are less efficient when executed on a 32 bit machine, only profiling would tell you whether or not it actually matters.

Perhaps the bottom line is that programmers should not be wilfully profligate. Why use 64 bits, if 32 bits suffice?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The data type is supported on both. But the 64 bit integer isn't native to 32 bit processors. If you use a 64 bit type, and you compile for 64 bit only (you can choose x64 or x86 (=32bit) as a targer), then the compiler might use specific 64 bit instructions, making your application run a bit faster. Theoretically, that is, in practice you will probably not notice this.

The tradeoff is that that application will not run on a 32 bit platform. The other way around will work. So if you plan to target both platforms, you need to either compile to 32 bit only, or compile two times, once for each platform.

For the availability of the `long` type it doesn't matter. You can always use it.

Comment: @GolezTrol On .net, there is AnyCPU, where you compile once, and the jitter makes either x86 or x64 executable

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know. You can choose that as well as the two options I mentioned. Choosing AnyCPU is the easy choice, but you can only do that if any dependencies you have also support both platforms. If one of them is explicitly compiled for either x86 or x64 then choosing 'Any CPU' will get you into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can try yourself like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(long));
```

Then compile it as `x86` instead of `AnyCPU` and run it. You can run 32 bit programs on 64 bit Windows as well - see what the result is.

There are even larger number types such as [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and they also work on 32 and 64 bit operating systems.